# Spark with yarn cluster in docker

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I worked with my spark project as standalone mode (in eclipse IDE). Here is some code that I used (working well).

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
.setAppName("My Application")
.setMaster("local[*]") 
.set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
.set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")

SparkSession.builder
.config(conf)
.appName("spark app")
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///.")
.getOrCreate()
}
```

Until now, I wrapped this application as a jar and used in another java project.

Now I'm going to change it to yarn clustering mode for multi user. So, I installed hadoop clustering in docker with this image([link](https://github.com/kiwenlau/hadoop-cluster-docker)).

1. I think It's already set yarn configuration. Do i need to do something more to do spark yarn cluster?
2. How should I set sparkConf? How pass hadoop ip, my application jar and other infomation needed?

Comment: Have you read official configuration? http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

Comment: yes, It's with 'spark-submit' and seems working with same node, unlike my case.

Comment: if you are using spark 1.6 I would suggest using sequenceiq/spark image. it has Yarn Hadoop and Spark. they also have an example of how to run spark-submit in yarn cluster mode

Comment: You need different master: `setMaster('yarn')`. Spark should pick up the YARN cluster config from environment variable HADOOP_CONF_DIR

Comment: @TalJoffe I need to work with java, not spark-submit. Where should I put my jar and how to request job to that container in java?

Comment: @J.Done Exact same thing. when you use spark-submit you state the name of the jar and main class. once it is compiled there is no difference between Scala and Java in this regard

Comment: @TalJoffe I don't think I need state main class becasue I just do some scala code with spark session in java.

Comment: @J.Done I've been submitting spark scala applications in production for a while now.. this is how I do it. I'm pretty sure it is how it is done. If you haven't already you should check out spark programming guide (specifically http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Comment: Still having hard time with it but thanks anyway. I'm looking for programical way like sparkcontext, not executing spark-submit. I need to look up other things.

Comment: did you try spark-shell? @J.Done

Comment: no, I want to execute spark job in java/scala jar or application.